# how to quote a quote from a mathematician?

Tags: quotation

In my project, at a paragraph I want to quote a saying from Newton as follow

`"Absolute, true and mathematical time, of itself, and from its own nature flows equably without regard to anything external, and by another name is called duration: relative, apparent and common time, is some sensible and external "`

But I want it to indent some space from both left and right margins compare to the main text, just like

`Newton said`

`"Absolute, true and mathematical time, of itself, and from its own`

`nature flows equably without regard to anything external, and by..."`

So how can I make it ? Please help, thank.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile. Your class determines how quotations and quotes are formatted in the first instance. And please edit your title. As far as I can tell, it isn't relevant you're quoting a mathematician. You just want a non-standard quotation style. What you should specify is whether this is a one-off thing, something you want to do for a number of quotations in the document (but not all) or the format you want for all quotations.

Comment: Incidentally, if this is an English document, you almost certainly do not want quotation marks in addition to this formatting. Logically, that would mean Newton was quoting somebody else when he said or wrote it.

Comment: The `quote` environment (`\begin{quote}...\end{quote}`) does something like this, usually.  Is that what you're wanting?  Or some modification?  If you're wanting a modification, please provide a complete example that indicates what you have and what you want to change.

Comment: @Teepeemm yeah I think the quote environment is exactly what I aim for. Thank you for your  significant help.

Comment: @Teepeemm An answer? I've been looking for a dupe but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is the intended use of the `quote` environment:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % just for this document

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

Newton said
\begin{quote}
Absolute, true and mathematical time, of itself, and from its own nature flows equably without regard to anything external, and by another name is called duration: relative, apparent and common time, is some sensible and external
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Having used `article` and `showframe`, the above results in:
[image: code output]

Note that the indent on the left and right is about twice the normal paragraph indent.  If you're wanting to adjust that, then you'll need to start digging into some weeds.  (The lines on the left and right are from the `showframe` package to show where the textwidth starts and ends.)

And as cfr noted, the `quote` environment is sufficient to indicate this is a quotation.  Also having quotation marks would be redundant or even suggest that Newton was in turn quoting someone else.

Comment: so when I creare a quote environment and I want to put the name of the mathematicians who said the quote at the end of the environent, how can I do it ?

Comment: @PermQi Ending with `\\\hfill Newton` would insert a linebreak, and then place "Newton" at the right.